# What does Thoreau mean by "pew hire" in this paragraph from "Slavery in Massachusetts"?

Tags: historical-context, essays, henry-david-thoreau, slavery-in-massachusetts

In [*Slavery in Massachusetts*](https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/70123/pg70123-images.html#Page_97), Thoreau writes:

> Among measures to be adopted, I would suggest to make as earnest and vigorous an assault
> on the press as has already been made, and with effect, on the church. The church has much
> improved within a few years; but the press is almost, without exception, corrupt.
> I believe that, in this country, the press exerts a greater and a more pernicious influence
> than the church did in its worst period. We are not a religious people, but we are a nation
> of politicians. We do not care for the Bible, but we do care for the newspaper. At any meeting
> of politicians,—like that at Concord the other evening, for instance,—how impertinent it would
> be to quote from the Bible! how pertinent to quote from a newspaper or from the Constitution!
> The newspaper is a Bible which we read every morning and every afternoon, standing and sitting,
> riding and walking. It is a Bible which every man carries in his pocket, which lies on every
> table and counter, and which the mail, and thousands of missionaries, are continually dispersing.
> It is, in short, the only book which America has printed, and which America reads. So wide is
> its influence. The editor is a preacher whom you voluntarily support. Your tax is commonly one
> cent daily, **and it costs nothing for pew hire**.

What does the author mean by [pew](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pew#Noun) [hire](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hire#Noun)? At first, I thought that Thoreau may refer here
to hiring a readership of a newspaper - but why would that cost nothing? I get it that with the
advancements of the technology of printing it may cost very little, but Thoreau himself seems
to recognize such cost, *Your tax is commonly one
cent daily, [...]*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this piece Thoreau is comparing the press with the church. The newspaper is equated with the Bible, the newspaper editor is identified with a preacher, and the cost of the newspaper ("one cent daily")  is related to the taxes levied to support the church and clergy (such as a tithe).

A "pew" is *[a long wooden seat with a high back, on which a row of people sit in a church](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pew)*. If a rich or important family wants to reserve a pew for their personal use, for example, if they all want to sit together in the front row, they can do so by paying a pew-hire. Pew-hire was [especially common in the United States](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pew#Pew_rents) as a means for the church to raise income, as churches lacked governmental support through mandatory tithing. Thoreau contrasts this with the case of reading a newspaper. A person wanting to listen to the preacher, i.e. read the newspaper articles, can sit anywhere they want at no cost - in their house, in a park, or at a bench in the street. No pew-hire is required.

Comment: It might be useful to note that the practice of hiring or renting a pew was already controversial in some circles at that time, and died out in the twentieth century. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pew#Pew_rents